# Android Custom Dijkstra Map

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, dijkstra

I need to implement a map for a shopping mall in my app. This map needs to have a way to visually mark the fastest path to go from one place to another.

I currently have two options in mind. I could use the Google Maps API, overlay the shopping mall's picture and try to use some algorithm to mark the best route. Or, I could just place the picture and manually make an algorithm to mark the path (probably Dijkstra).

Yet, it's my first time working with Android, and I don't really know which one could work the best, and which libraries I could use.

I'd appreciate any tip or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Google map has an android api that you can directly embed google maps into your application. You can also draw overlays using its api. Take a look at 
[google map android api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)